# 404 not found laravel 5.2 after publish on server

Tags: laravel

i got error 404 not found on laravel 5.2 after i deployed my project on ubuntu server 16.04

i gave permission to storage and too i created virtual host and its directory on public folder of my project

```
Not Found
The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at www.xxx.com Port 80
```

the laravel home page show but nothing work like login and register

Comment: Did you give permission to all folders inside the storage folder? It's a common issue.

Comment: @CésarFerreira yeah bro i did it

Comment: Can you show us your vhost?

Comment: @ChinLeung no brother it's ok

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer

you should run this on server:

> a2enmod rewrite

that worked perfectly! xD